# How to find values in a range with .FindNext?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find cells with a value of "b" in range A1:A14. There are three such values in that range.
If a value is found, then set B2 to "yes", and then offset one row below.

In this code I wrote the `findNext` function doesn't work.

```
Sub sinep()

Dim sinepRng As Range
Dim rangeRover As Range

Set rangeRover = Range("B2")
Set sinepRng = Range("A1:A14").Find("b", LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not sinepRng Is Nothing Then
    firstAddress = sinepRng.Address
    MsgBox "first address " & firstAddress
    Do
    rangeRover.Value = "yes"
    Set rangeRover = rangeRover.Offset(1, 0)
    Set sinepRng = Range("A1:A14").Find("b").FindNext(sinepRng)
    MsgBox "third address " & sinepRng.Address
    If sinepRng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "isnothing"
        GoTo DoneFinding
        End If
    Loop While sinepRng.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
DoneFinding:
```

This code does work.

```
Sub nag()

Dim rangeRover As Range
Set rangeRover = Range("B2")

With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a500")
     Set c = .Find("b", LookIn:=xlValues)
     If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            rangeRover.Value = "yes"
            Set rangeRover = rangeRover.Offset(1, 0)
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        If c Is Nothing Then
            GoTo DoneFinding
        End If
        Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress
      End If
DoneFinding:
End With

End Sub
```

I figure the problem lies within the `findNext`. I tried modifying it without success. I also tried using `Find` with After parameter.

Comment: `Set sinepRng = Range("A1:A14").Find("b").FindNext(sinepRng)` looks very suspect.

Comment: Remove the `.Find("b")` part of that line.

Comment: @Rory thanks, that did it! I don't know why I imagined I needed to restate the .Find in that line.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Rory for the solution.

I had to remove `.find("b")` from the line `Set sinepRng = Range("A1:A14").Find("b").FindNext(sinepRng)`.